# non-www domain causing issues with SSL and heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I have a site with SSL. everything works fine with www (the subdomain the SSL is registered under) but if I try to go to the non-www version it says:

```
You attempted to reach mywebsite.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.heroku.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of mywebsite.com.
```

How do I make the non-www work with ssl OR make sure that the non-www redirects to the proper www before attempting to use SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite some of the older Heroku documentation it is possible to use the naked (non-www) domain with a matching SSL certificate.  However, you'll have to have a way to redirect www traffic to the naked domain and this can be problematic with some DNS providers.  It is possible with DNS Made Easy's new ANAME records.

Having just been in the exact situation you describe, I used the www subdomain for SSL and put a lightweight Sinatra app together to handle redirections from the naked domain to the www subdomain:

https://github.com/kjohnston/naked_redirect

This Sinatra app deploys very easily to Heroku and of course you can run it there for free.  There are third party services that provide this same type of redirection, but I didn't want to be pointing my client's domain at some random service in hopes that they always redirect properly when I could put a solution like this up and be in full control.

Comment: Is there a way to also create the redirect using the web server? For example in the .htaccess file?

Comment: i dont really care about using the non-www version. So, I setup a redirect from non-www to www using zerigo dns redirect. However, it doesn't seem to be working all the time. I still get some ssl warnings on some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I can not get this to work as well it’s driving me crazy making me want to move away from heroku wish I hadn’t started with it.

I am using route53 I have and s3 bucket named as my domain example.com and in properties set it as a redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I have my alias set in route53 and my www subdomain set to heroku.

http://example.com
Redirects to
https://www.example.com

http://www.example.com
Redirects to
https://www.example.com

https://example.com
This does nothing doesn’t go anywhere meaning my website seems to have issue ranking in google for some reason.

I’ve setup a redirect in my nextjs app to force https.

There are no clear tutorials on how to setup ssl on heroku naked or www I don’t even think it’s possible. Hours wasted on this.